# Autocomplete using jQuery not working in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

I am using jQuery autocomplete in 2 places on the same page, one in the header and one in the body of the page. Both work fine in Firefox and Chrome. However in IE, the autocomplete in the header works fine, but not the one in the body.

Could someone please let me know what the problem could be and a possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

Given the lack of examples, I'm only guessing based on a problem I had yesterday with IE7 and the jQuery autocomplete plugin.

In the source code, there is a section of code around line 281 that looks like this:

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
    // we put a styled iframe behind the calendar so HTML SELECT elements don't show through
    $results.append(document.createElement('iframe'));
}
```

Comment it out, clear your browser cache, and try again.